# Efficient file ordering for byte diffiing?

Tags: algorithm, filesystems, libraries

I'm trying to find the 'best' way to order two lists of files so that a diff patch between them is small in general.

The way to do this without any other 'heuristics' that may fail easily (natural name order, parsing index files like cues to figured out natural sequential orders) seems to be to analyze the bytes on files on both collections, and figure out a sequence that minimizes the 'distance' between them.

This actually reminds me Levenshtein distance applied to segments of the bytes in the files (possibly with a constraint segments of the same file are in order to minimize permutations). Is there a library around that can figure out this for me? Notice that it's likely for the header or footer of files that are 'technically the same' to be different (ex: different dump format).

My main use case is to figure out the distance between two kinds of cd dumps. It's pretty normal for a cd dump to be segmented in different ways. I could just figure out their 'natural' order from the index files (cue, ccd etc) but why waste a opportunity to get something that applies generally (that works with extra files in the source or destination, or files segmented in different ways or to compare things that aren't cd dumps)?

I'd prefer a library in python if you know of any?

BTW I already have something implemented [zxd3](https://github.com/i30817/zxd3/) but it's pretty much using the 'natural order' heuristic, i'd like to improve it (and make it work on more than two zips).

Comment: *Any* measure will group identical files. One easy to evaluate is "byte value histogram" (or, for "text", "word frequency"). Have an eye on file size… (Ogling the code on GIT, you may be looking for a way to make zip diffs useful - no dice.)

Comment: Ahh, the problem with 'comparing whole files' is that the ordering should be resistant to comparing a segmented file (with extra or missing metadata) to a whole file. For example, imagine a ISO (mode1/2048) with wav audio tracks compared to a bin (mode2/2352) with audio tracks concatenated to the bin.